# How can I get the window focused on Windows and re-size it?

Tags: python, windows

I want to get the focused window so I can resize it... how can I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API to get the window handle.

Then use the [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx) (or [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) if you prefer) win32 API to resize the window.

Working with the Win32 API can be done directly with ctypes and working with the dlls or by using the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) project.

**Edit:** Sure here is an example ([Make sure you have pywin32 installed](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)):

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 500, 500, True)
```