# setting python command line position

Tags: python, command-line, positioning, vpython

I am wondering if there is a way to set the position of where the command line opens. I am using python 2.7 with VPython for my A-Level computing project. It currently opens behind the two VPython windows, but I would prefer it to open underneath so was just wondering if this was possible. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the command line"? How are you launching Python?

Comment: The program is launched by launching the .py from windows explore, I will attach a photo.
http://tinypic.com/r/260yl29/6
this is what happens when it is opened by launching the .py file
http://tinypic.com/r/2d9npi/6
The command line is hidden behind my two windows, I know how to set the position of my two other windows, but I am not sure if it is possible to change where the command line opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't "own" the console it's running in.

For a Windows-specific answer you could look into the Win32 APIs that control window focus, size, and position. See this question for more information: [How can I get the window focused on Windows and re-size it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335721/how-can-i-get-the-window-focused-on-windows-and-re-size-it)