# Taking a print screen of a particular window using PIL using Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to take a print screen of a particular window on my PC by running the python program and it taking that screen shot, before cropping it and comparing its hex value to other hex values in a SQL server.

I have thought about letting it wait 10 seconds whilst I get the other window up and then start taking the print screens continuously until one matches.

I was just wondering if I can use python to maximize that particular window that I want to print screen  automatically and then have it take a print screen.

If not, could I take a print screen (a picture) of a window that is minimized? (I think this is impossible)..

Thanks!

Comment: Your last paragraph which asks the question is not very clear.  Could you try to fix that: maybe break it into a few sentences; be clear on whether "print screen" is a noun or a verb; etc?  Are you just trying to open a gui program from within a python script?  Or maybe you're trying to maximize a minimized window?  Or maybe you're trying to do a screen capture at a particular time?

Comment: Sorry, will change that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a quick Google search, you will find this helpful tutorial that uses PIL to take a screenshot of a desktop:

- http://www.blendedtechnologies.com/quick-screenshots-script-python-pil/38

Assuming you're on Windows, you would need to use [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) (or possibly [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/)) to get the window you want. These two links will help with that:

- [Get HWND of each Window Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window-python)
- http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/find-the-window-for-my-subprocess.html

Then you could use MoveWindow to resize the window you found before taking the screenshot:

- [How can I get the window focused on Windows and re-size it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335721/how-can-i-get-the-window-focused-on-windows-and-re-size-it)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to only use PIL but I think I've got to use PyWin32.

Comment: If you need to take a screenshot of a specific window that you didn't create (i.e. Notepad, MS Word, etc), then yes, you'll almost certainly need PyWin32