# How to change window sizes/dimensions via Python

Tags: python, resize, window

I want to write a program, preferably in Python, that will change the window size of any particular application I have open. E.g. say I have Notepad open and wish to make it 640x400 - my script would recognise the window and change its dimensions automatically.

Is there an available framework in Python for this or do I need to use another language?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python
And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335721/how-can-i-get-the-window-focused-on-windows-and-re-size-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the window focused on Windows and re-size it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335721/how-can-i-get-the-window-focused-on-windows-and-re-size-it)

Answer (score 12):

```
import pygetwindow
win = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
win.size = (640, 400)
```